# CloudFoundry websocket failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, cloud-foundry

Note: I am not using Pivotal CF.

I have a java application deployed on CloudFoundry. I am using embedded Jetty to host my Jersey REST API. This API is by default exposed on port 8080 by cloud foundry.

My application also needs some websockets to stream data to the browser. I am using Java-WebSocket (https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) for this. On my local machine, I was using port 8887 for my websocket connection. Everything worked fine.

After deploying on CloudFoundry, I can access my REST API but not my websocket. After searching a bit online, I found that websocket connections are only allowed on port 4443 (http://docs.run.pivotal.io/release-notes/)

I changed my server side to reflect this

```
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;
public class MyWebSocket extends WebSocketServer {
    public MyWebSocket() throws UnknownHostException {
        super(new InetSocketAddress(4443));
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(org.java_websocket.WebSocket websocket, ClientHandshake handshake) {
      // Handle this
      }
}
```

On my client side, I am connecting the websocket using the following

```
wss://my_cf_app.com:4443/
```

But I am getting the following exception.

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://my_cf_app.com:4443/' failed:
>   Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed

I also tried to connect the websocket on server side using "PORT" environment variable of CF but I get "Address already in use" error in Java-WebSocket.

I have tried many different things but I am unable to figure this out. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Why aren't you using the WebSocket server support built into embedded-jetty?

Comment: My REST API is in Jersey deployed on Jetty. I tried to get websockets running on Jersey but I failed. That is why I moved to another library. Let's say I implement websockts on Jetty, will it work on CF ? I mean REST API on Jersey and socket on Jetty ? Will I be able to serve both using 8080 port of CF ?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of websocket, its just an upgraded HTTP connection, using the same server, same connectors, same port, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

> After deploying on CloudFoundry, I can access my REST API but not my websocket. After searching a bit online, I found that websocket connections are only allowed on port 4443 (http://docs.run.pivotal.io/release-notes/)

Port 4443 is specific to Pivotal Web Services (and some installs of CF that run on AWS).  Most PCF installs do not have a separate port for WSS, but just use 443 along with the HTTPS traffic.  The port used ultimately depends on the load balancer being used in front of the CF installation and what it supports.

You would *never* have your application listen on port 4443.  Port 4443 is the external port for traffic where the load balancer listens.  This traffic will be directed to the port assigned to your application, which is $PORT (env variable).

> I also tried to connect the websocket on server side using "PORT" environment variable of CF but I get "Address already in use" error in Java-WebSocket.

This is the correct behavior, i.e. you should be listening on the port assigned through $PORT env variable.  What the error is telling you is that something is already listening on this port and you cannot have two things listening on the same port.

There is only *one* port available per application at this time (likely to change in the future).  For now, if you have two separate applications listening on two separate ports then you need to push them to CF as two separate applications.

What you can do to make them appear like one application to end users is to map each one to a specific path.  See the `--route-path` argument of `cf push` or docs for `cf create-route`.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#create-route

Comment: Hmm so you are saying that only one port is exposed to CF applications which is specified in env variable "PORT". For more ports we need to have separate deployments :( ?

Comment: Yes, for the time being external traffic is only sent to one port in the app container.  You can listen on multiple ports, they're just not accessible and no traffic will go to them.  Unless you were to have something that acts as a proxy in your app.  Ex:  proc-1 listens on 5000, proc-2 listens on port 5001.  No external traffic will come to these ports.  Now if proc-3 listens on $PORT and forwards traffic to proc-1 & proc-2 ports then external traffic will get to 5000 & 5001, but you'd need to set that up and it's easier to just have two apps.

Comment: got it. Thank you for the information. Btw my application is pretty simple (it is a demo actually), I load the page .... click a button which starts the socket and uses the stream on the page. Then if the user presses STOP, i just inform the server. Maybe, once the page is loaded,

Comment: I can disconnect Jetty from the port 8080 and bind websocket to this port and push data. Once the data is pushed, disconnect websocket and bind again. I am not sure if that is possible, might work.